# how do I get all my posts in a category to show up in React?

Tags: reactjs, json

At the moment Im using UseParams to find all my posts within a certain category. The category below is "short stories" but only the first post is appearing. How do I get it to find all the post with the "short stories" category? Thanks in advance. Below is my short stories blog page and a snippet my JSON file where the data is stored.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate, useParams  }
from "react-router-dom";




export default function ShortStories ({ posts, setCart, cart,  }) {
const { category } = useParams();
const post = posts.find(post => post.category === "SHORT_STORIES");



  return (
   <>
  <h1>Short Stories</h1>


      <Link to="/ShortStories"><button type="button">Short Stories</button></Link>
      <Link to="/KentBased"><button type="button">Kent Based</button></Link>
      <Link to="/Blog"><button type="button">All</button></Link>



    <div className="products">

        <div className="product">
          <h3>{post.name}</h3>
          <h4>£{post.cost}</h4>
          <img src={post.image} alt={post.name} />
          <br />





          <Link to={`/SingleBlog/${post.id}`}><button type="button">View 
     Post</button></Link>


        </div>

      </div>

    </>
    );
    }
```

and a snippet from my JSON file

```
{
"postsData" :
 [
 {
  "id": "0001",
  "category": "SHORT_STORIES",
  "name": "Blueberry Muffins (Pages 4 & 5)",
  "image":"/images/BlueberryMuffins.jpg",
  "main": "SOME BLOG POST 1"

  },
   {   "id": "0002",
    "category": "SHORT_STORIES",
    "name": "Cheese on Toast (Page 3)",
    "image":"/images/cheese.jpg",
    "main": "SOME BLOG POST 2"

      }
      ]}
```

Comment: use `filter` not `find`. `find` will find the first result and exit.

Comment: `posts.filter(post => post.category === "SHORT_STORIES");`

Comment: thanks, I've tried using filter but for some reason it doesnt pick up my image and "main". Plus, it only seems to locate one in that category

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at the documentation of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it says that it returns the **first** value instead of all.

Use `filter` instead

```
const post = posts.filter(post => post.category === "SHORT_STORIES");
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried using filter but for some reason it doesnt pick up my image and "main". Plus, it only seems to locate one in that category

Comment: Can you then show some more code and show how you implemented this and where you see that it's failing. Because I tried this code with your json and the filter does work.